# Attribute event requires a static signal prefix in 8 -bit Multiplier in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I am implementing a multiplier in which i multiply A (8 bits) and B (8 bits), and store result at S.  Number of bit required for output S is 16 bits. S have higher part SH and lower part SL.Every time i shift ,add operation is performed
i am getting following errors in my controller part :-
Attribute event requires a static signal prefix
 is not declared.
 "**" expects 2 arguments

and my code is:-

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
entity  PIPO is
port (reset: in  std_logic ;
        B:IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0 );
        LOAD:in  std_logic ;
        SHIFT:in  std_logic ;
        ADD:in  std_logic ;
        Sum:IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0 );
        C_out:in  std_logic ;
        CLK:in  std_logic ;
        result: out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0) ;
        LSB:out std_logic ;
        TB:out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) );
    end ;

architecture rtl OF PIPO is
    signal temp1 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    ----temp2 -add 
    signal temp2 : std_logic ;
begin
process (CLK, reset)
  begin
    if reset='0' then
        temp1<= (others =>'0');
        temp2<= '0';
     elsif (CLK'event and CLK='1') then
        if LOAD ='1'  then
        temp1(7 downto 0) <= B; 
        temp1(15 downto 8) <= (others => '0');
    end if ;

    if ADD= '1' then
    temp2 <='1';
    end if;
    if SHIFT= '1' then
        if ADD= '1' then
        ------adder result ko add n shift

        temp2<= '0';
        temp1<=C_out & Sum & temp1( 7 downto 1 );

        else 
        ----only shift
        temp1<= '0' &  temp1( 15 downto 1 );
       end if;
    end if;

end if;
  end process;

  LSB <=temp1(0);
  result<=temp1( 15 downto 0 );
  TB <=temp1(15 downto 8);
    end architecture rtl;
-------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

    entity Controller is
Port ( ADD :OUT STD_LOGIC;
            SHIFT:OUT STD_LOGIC;
            LOAD:OUT STD_LOGIC;
            STOP:OUT STD_LOGIC;
            STRT:IN STD_LOGIC;
            LSB:IN STD_LOGIC;
            CLK:IN STD_LOGIC;
            reset:IN STD_LOGIC ); 
    end ;   
architecture rtl OF Contoller is
---RTL level code is inherently synchronous 
signal count : unsigned (2 downto 0);

----differnt states 
type state_typ is ( IDLE, INIT, TEST, ADDs, SHIFTs );
signal state : state_typ;


begin
--controller : process (ADD,SHIFT,LOAD,STOP,STRT,LSB,CLK,reset)
process (state)--(CLK, reset,ADD,SHIFT,LOAD,STOP,STRT,LSB)
  begin
    if reset='0' then
      state <= IDLE;
      count <= "000";
    elsif (CLK'event and CLK='1') then

            case state is
        when IDLE =>
          if STRT = '1' then
         --- if STRT = '1' then
            state <= INIT;
          else
            state <= IDLE;
          end if;
        when INIT =>
          state <= TEST;
        when TEST =>
          if LSB = '0' then
            state <= SHIFTs;
          else
            state <= ADDs;
          end if;
        when ADDs =>
          state <= SHIFTs;

        when SHIFTs =>
          if count = "111" then  
            count <= "000";      
            state <= IDLE;          
          else
            count<= std_logic_vector(unsigned(count) + 1);
            state <= TEST;
          end if;
      end case;
    end if;
  end process ;
  STOP <= '1' when state = IDLE else '0';
  ADD <= '1' when state = ADDs else '0';
  SHIFT <= '1' when state = SHIFTs else '0';
  LOAD <= '1' when state = INIT else '0';
end architecture rtl;




----------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------


---multiplicand
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;    
entity multiplicand is 
port (A : in std_logic(7 downto 0);
        reset :in std_logic;
        LOAD : in std_logic;
        TA : OUT STD_LOGIC(7 downto 0);
        CLK : in std_logic );
    end entity;     
architecture rtl OF multiplicand is
begin 
process (CLK, reset)
  begin
    if reset='0' then
      TA <= (others =>'0');  -- initialize 

    elsif (CLK'event and CLK='1') then
      if LOAD_cmd = '1' then
     TA(7 downto 0) <= A_in;  -- load B_in into register
      end if;
end if ;

end process;
end architecture rtl;   



------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------
---Full Adder
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity  Full_Adder  is
port (A     : in  std_logic;
      B     : in  std_logic;
      C_in  : in  std_logic;
      Sum   : out std_logic ;
      C_out : out std_logic);
end;
architecture  struc  of  Full_Adder  is
begin
Sum <= A xor B xor C_in;
C_out <= (A and B) or (A and C_in) or (B and C_in);
end struc;
------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------


library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Adder is
    Port ( TA : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           TB : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           Sum : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           C_in : in STD_LOGIC;
              C_out : out  STD_LOGIC);
end Adder;


architecture struc of Adder is
component Full_Adder is  
      port(A     : in  std_logic;
            B     : in  std_logic;
            C_in  : in  std_logic;
            Sum   : out std_logic ;
            C_out : out std_logic);
   end component;

    signal C: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0); 

begin
    FA0:Full_Adder port map(TA(0), TB(0), C_in,   Sum(0), C(0));
    FA1: Full_Adder port map(TA(1), TB(1), C(0),  Sum(1), C(1));
   FA3: Full_Adder port map(TA(2),TB(2), C(1),  Sum(2), C(2));
    FA4: Full_Adder port map(TA(3), TB(3), C(2),   Sum(3), C(3));
    FA5: Full_Adder port map(TA(4), TB(4), C(3),  Sum(4), C(4));
    FA6: Full_Adder port map(TA(5), TB(5), C(4),   Sum(5), C(5));
    FA7: Full_Adder port map(TA(6), TB(6), C(5),   Sum(6), C(6));
    FA8: Full_Adder port map(TA(7), TB(7), C(6),   Sum(7), C(7));

    C_out <= C(7);

end struc;
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
entity multiplier is
    Port ( num1 : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           num2 : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           result : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0); 
              CLK:in  std_logic ;
              reset:IN STD_LOGIC;
              STRT:IN STD_LOGIC;
              STOP:OUT STD_LOGIC );

end multiplier;

architecture rtl of Multiplier is
    signal ADD :STD_LOGIC;
    signal SHIFT :STD_LOGIC;
    signal LOAD :STD_LOGIC;
    signal LSB :STD_LOGIC;
    signal A : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
    signal B :STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
    signal Sum:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
    signal C_out:STD_LOGIC;

component Controller
      port (
            ADD :OUT STD_LOGIC;
            SHIFT:OUT STD_LOGIC;
            LOAD:OUT STD_LOGIC;
            STOP:OUT STD_LOGIC;
            STRT:IN STD_LOGIC;
            LSB:IN STD_LOGIC;
            CLK:IN STD_LOGIC;
            reset:IN STD_LOGIC );

         end component;     
component Adder 
        port ( 
                TA : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           TB : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           Sum : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           C_in : in STD_LOGIC;
              C_out : out  STD_LOGIC);

         end component;
component PIPO
    port (reset: in  std_logic ;
        B:IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0 );
        LOAD:in  std_logic ;
        SHIFT:in  std_logic ;
        ADD:in  std_logic ;
        Sum:IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0 );
        C_out:in  std_logic ;
        CLK:in  std_logic ;
        result: out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0) ;
        LSB:out std_logic ;
        TB:out std_logic );

end component;
    component multiplicand 
    port (A : in std_logic (7 downto 0);
        reset :in std_logic;
        LOAD : in std_logic;
        TA : OUT STD_LOGIC(7 downto 0);
        CLK : in std_logic );
end component ;
begin

inst_Controller: Controller
port map (ADD => ADD,
            SHIFT =>SHIFT,
            LOAD =>LOAD ,
            STOP =>STOP,
            STRT =>STRT,
            LSB =>LSB ,
            CLK =>CLK ,
            reset =>reset
            );
inst_multiplicand :multiplicand     
port map (A =>A,
        reset=>reset,
        LOAD =>LOAD,
        TA => TA(7 downto 0),
        CLK => CLK
            );      


inst_PIPO :PIPO
port map ( reset => reset,
        B => B ,
        LOAD =>LOAD,
        SHIFT=>SHIFT,
        ADD=>ADD,
        Sum=>Sum,
        C_out=>C_out,
        CLK=>CLK,
        result=>result,
        LSB=>LSB,
        TB=>TB
            );

inst_Full_Adder : Full_Adder
        port map ( TA => TA,
           TB =>TB,
           Sum=>Sum ,
           C_in=>C_in,
              C_out=>C_out 
              );


end rtl;
```

Comment: `'event` has no prefix as the error message and Russell tell you. Also the entity names don't match between the entity and architecture declarations, and you are initialising Count to ... a string apparently, not an integer.

Comment: What VHDL tool is giving the complaint?  It doesn't appear to be VHDL standard compliant.

Answer (score 1):

**Actually the space between CLK and the apostrophe/tick isn't significant**

```
david_koontz@Macbook: token_test
elsif (CLK 'event and CLK ='1') then
KEYWD_ELSIF             (151)   elsif
DELIM_LEFT_PAREN        (  9)   (
IDENTIFIER_TOKEN        (128)   CLK
DELIM_APOSTROPHE        (  8)   '
IDENTIFIER_TOKEN        (128)   event
KEYWD_AND               (134)   and
IDENTIFIER_TOKEN        (128)   CLK
DELIM_EQUAL             ( 25)   =
CHAR_LIT_TOKEN          (  2)   '1'
DELIM_RIGHT_PAREN       ( 10)   )
KEYWD_THEN              (211)   then
```

gives the same answer as:

```
david_koontz@Macbook: token_test
elsif (CLK'event and CLK ='1') then
KEYWD_ELSIF             (151)   elsif
DELIM_LEFT_PAREN        (  9)   (
IDENTIFIER_TOKEN        (128)   CLK
DELIM_APOSTROPHE        (  8)   '
IDENTIFIER_TOKEN        (128)   event
KEYWD_AND               (134)   and
IDENTIFIER_TOKEN        (128)   CLK
DELIM_EQUAL             ( 25)   =
CHAR_LIT_TOKEN          (  2)   '1'
DELIM_RIGHT_PAREN       ( 10)   )
KEYWD_THEN              (211)   then
```

In vhdl, there is no lexical element parsing requiring a lack of white space.  (Sorry Russel).

Correcting the other syntax ambiguities of your code (see below, missing context clause, Controller misspelled in the architecture declaration, `count` used as both a scalar and array subtype), results in two different VHDL analyzers swallowing the space between CLK and ' just fine.

The problem is in the tool you are using not actually being standard compliant or the code you present as having the problem isn't actually representational of the code generating the error.  If a non-compliant tool it's likely a shortcoming you can live with, although there may be more things a bit more irksome.

> david_koontz@Macbook: ghdl -a controller.vhdl
>   david_koontz@Macbook: nvc -a controller.vhdl
>   david_koontz@Macbook:

(no errors, it also elaborates without a test bench in ghdl, nvc disallows top level ports - which it is permitted to do by the standard)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Controller is
    Port ( 
        ADD:    OUT STD_LOGIC;
        SHIFT:  OUT STD_LOGIC;
        LOAD:   OUT STD_LOGIC;
        STOP:   OUT STD_LOGIC;
        STRT:   IN  STD_LOGIC;
        LSB:    IN  STD_LOGIC;
        CLK:    IN  STD_LOGIC;
        reset:  IN  STD_LOGIC 
    ); 
end entity;   

architecture rtl OF Controller is
    ---RTL level code is inherently synchronous 
    signal count : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);

    ----differnt states 
    type state_typ is ( IDLE, INIT, TEST, ADDs, SHIFTs );
    signal state : state_typ;

begin
NOLABEL:
    process (CLK, reset)
    begin
        if reset='0' then
          state <= IDLE;
          count <= "000";
        elsif (CLK 'event and CLK ='1') then

                case state is
            when IDLE =>
              if STRT = '1' then
                state <= INIT;
              else
                state <= IDLE;
              end if;
            when INIT =>
              state <= TEST;
            when TEST =>
              if LSB = '0' then
                state <= SHIFTs;
              else
                state <= ADDs;
              end if;
            when ADDs =>
              state <= SHIFTs;

            when SHIFTs =>
              if count = "111" then  -- verify if finished
                count <= "000";      -- re-initialize counter
                state <= IDLE;            -- ready for next multiply
              else
                count <=             -- increment counter
                    std_logic_vector(unsigned(count) + 1); 
                state <= TEST;
              end if;
          end case;
        end if;
    end process;
  ---end generate; ???

    STOP <= '1' when state = IDLE else '0';
    ADD <= '1' when state = ADDs else '0';
    SHIFT <= '1' when state = SHIFTs else '0';
    LOAD <= '1' when state = INIT else '0';
end architecture rtl;
```

The error message appears to stem from the signal `CLK` (the prefix for the event attribtute).  There is no other use of the event attribute in your code presented with the question. A signal is one of the elements of entity_class that can be decorated with an attribute.

In the VHDL LRM's section on predefined attributes `'EVENT` can only decorate a signal, and `CLK` is a signal (declared in a port).  In that section the prefix is required to be denoted by a static signal name.

Is `CLK` a static signal name?  Yes it is.  It's a scalar subtype declared in the entity declaration and is locally static (available at analysis time - it's a scalar, a simple name and not involving a generic).

And about now you might get why someone would wonder if the code in the question is representational of the code generating the error or the VHDL tool used is not compliant.

The error message you report is usually associated with trying to use `'EVENT` with an indexed signal name, e.g. `w(i)'event`. (See [Signal attributes on a signal vector](http://computer-programming-forum.com/42-vhdl/ca12e49f63c3954f.htm)).

Answer (score 0):

You're going to kick yourself for this one:

```
elsif (CLK 'event and CLK ='1') then
```

Should be:

```
elsif (CLK'event and CLK ='1') then
```

See the difference?

Even better:

```
elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing a clk entry in the process

Change the line reading:

```
process (state)--(CLK, reset,ADD,SHIFT,LOAD,STOP,STRT,LSB)
```

to read:

```
process (clk, reset)
```